# Can you generate XML or JSON from SQL Server metadata?

Tags: json, sql-server, xml

I have a PowerShell script that uses SQL Server Management Objects (SMO) to create a .SQL file containing all the metadata from a SQL Server database. However, SMO cannot natively generate XML or JSON output. Is there a means to turn the .SQL output into either of these formats?

Comment: Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72325283/edit) your question to include an example of this SQL-formatted metadata and a snippet of code that generates it.

Comment: Depending on what this "metadata" is almost certainly yes, you can query the system tables and format the output for json in t-sql.

Comment: Powershell has has the means https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-json  https://mattou07.net/posts/creating-complex-json-with-powershell/ T-SQL has the means  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/format-query-results-as-json-with-for-json-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: I edited my question with snippets of the output and the PS code that generates the output per Dale's request.  I will look into the ConvertTO-Json PS option that Nick D. mentioned.

Comment: Thanks all for the references.  I cobbled together a command that turns the .sql output into an object, then calls ConverTo-Json for the conversion.

Answer (score 0):

In SMO you can script individual objects to strings with the [Scripter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/server-management-objects-smo/tasks/scripting?view=sql-server-ver15), and then use .NET libraries to add those scripts to a custom class which you serialize to XML/JSON, or use the XML and JSON libraries to construct the document directly.